# Format Image to Press Up Against Table (HTML)

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to get the social media sprites in this HTML table at https://www.alexcurriemedia.com/video/ to press up flush with the image above it. Cannot figure out a way to do this.

Can't add another table  above it because the upper image is a wordpress shortcode that doesn't seem to work within the table.

Here is the code:

```
<table><center>[wds id="3"] 
<td nowrap><a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank">
<div class='sprite Facebook1' width="100"></div></a></td>
<td nowrap><a href="http://www.twitter.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank">
<div class='sprite Twitter1'></div></a></td>
<td nowrap><a href="http://www.flickr.com/alexcurrie" target="_blank">
<div class='sprite Flickr1'></div></a></td>
<td nowrap><a href="http://www.alexcurriemedia.tumblr.com" target="_blank">
<div class='sprite Tumblr1'></div></a></td>
<td nowrap><a href="http://www.instagram.com/alex.currie" target="_blank">
<div class='sprite Instagram1'></div></a></td><td></td>
</center></table>
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: You do realize that the actual HTML on the page for those cells looks like `<td nowrap><a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank"></p>
<div class='sprite Facebook1' width="100"></div>
<p></a></td>` right? You have an errant `</p>` in each cell.

Comment: `<table>` cannot contain `<center>` element, not in HTML4 nor in HTML5

Comment: <center> removed still does not remove the space between the image and the sprites, and according to my html on the page there is no errant <p> tag unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The stray `<p>` tags that you see are likely a result of Wordpress automatically inserting them through the text editor. You should not place a `<div>` inside of an `<a>` tag if at all possible. While technically valid, I've seen it cause problems with things such as Wordpress's text editor. If you look at the source code in your browser, you will notice that the link is actually being rendered twice, like so:

`<td nowrap="">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank"><p></p>
            <div class="sprite Twitter1"></div>
            </a>
            <p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank"></a>
            </p>
        </td>`

The following code should work better:

`<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td nowrap>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank" class="sprite Facebook1"></a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>
            <a class="sprite Twitter1" href="http://www.twitter.com/alexcurriemedia" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>
            <a class="sprite Flickr1" href="http://www.flickr.com/alexcurrie" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>
            <a class="sprite Tumblr1" href="http://www.alexcurriemedia.tumblr.com" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>
            <a class="sprite Instagram1" href="http://www.instagram.com/alex.currie" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`

Once you change that, simply add the following to your CSS:

`.sprite {
    display: block;
}`

This will cause the content in each `<td>` to align at the top, rather than in the center as they are doing currently.

If you still have trouble with the `<p>` tags being automatically inserted, you may look into [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).

End result:

[image: Flush Social Sprite Image]